# How Can You Find A Writing Buddy?

Tags: creative-writing, collaboration, writing-groups

I have noticed I work best in collaboration with another.
I am extremely prolific and have a lot of time for writing.

So how do you find that reliable, positive person who is deeply involved in playing with you?

Comment: In person? Have you tried the library? Online? I use Critique Circle now. It's solid.

Comment: @ChrisSunami i have also left my contacts in my profile - add me because i am on the phone

Answer (score 2):

The website http://co-writers.com/ is specifically set up to help people find writing partners.  It's not the most active site, but it gets a steady stream of postings, and doesn't charge for usage.