# How To Meet Fellow Writers Online?

Tags: creative-writing, collaboration, social-media

So where are the forums, the groups, the social networks in which writers dwell in harmony and happy collaboration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can You Find A Writing Buddy?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/21876/how-can-you-find-a-writing-buddy)

Comment: There are towns named Harmony in NY, NJ, Wisconsin, Maine, and North Carolina, and I'm sure some writers live there, but I can't speak to collaborations, happy or otherwise.

Comment: I've been using *Critique Circle* recently. It's pretty good. If you do sci-fi/fantasy, *Critters* is good, too. Both come with typical online "Whoa, this dude is crazy" crap. But I'm sure that's what they think of me, soooo ...

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad. There are a LOT of existing communities and resources! If you're looking for something for a specific purpose, or to fulfill a specific need, that's likely to be a fine question. But also, start by just Googling "writing sites" and "writing communities" - you'll find lots and lots :)

Answer (score 1):

Last time I was there, [Forward Motion for Writers](http://fmwriters.com) was a thriving, helpful group.  Life issues stole the time which I used to spend there or I would still be an active participant.  My favorite feature was the genre specific critique circles where I could securely share small section of my writing with a consistent group of similar writers and trade critique services.